# How can I negatively charge a metallic surface?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering

I wish to negatively charge the surface of a fan blade in a [ceiling fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_fan). As the fan is connected to AC power, it is safe to assume that we have electric power at our disposal. Also this surface needs to have charge for as long as the fan is running and not a one time spike.

Please suggest workable options to realize this.

Comment: It might help if you mentioned why you are interested in doing this. For all any of us know, your fan blade may already be charged with some infinitesimal negative charge due to some subtle effect related to its motion through the air. Or are you interested in having a substantial negative charge on the fan blade(s)? If so, then define how much of a charge would be "substantial".

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am looking at a substantial charge to try and see if I can zap positively charged dust specs from the air. Can you please make an assumption on the amount and make a suggestion.

Comment: "Zap" positively charged dust specs from the air? Like vaporize them with energy from a static discharge?

Comment: @SamuelWeir I'm assuming he means that he's electrostatically attracting them to the fan blade. This necessitates cleaning of the fan blade every so often, but it's not _a priori_ a bad idea - in fact, this is indeed how some air filters work.

Comment: @probably_someone - Well, yeah. In fact, I was going to suggest to him that he go look up information on electrostatic air filters rather than pursue this questionable idea of trying to use charged fan blades to somehow remove dust from the air.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I'm not sure why you think this idea is "questionable." Fan blades already become charged just through the triboelectric effect with the air, which is why they collect dust at such a high rate compared to their surroundings. So why is it unreasonable to consider deliberately charging them to get a scaled-up version of the same effect?

Comment: Gentlemen, will appreciate any workable ideas to adding charge well beyond the natural static charge via friction with air. The key thing to consider is that as the blades are moving pretty fast they cannot be mounted with any device. We will need to have the device housed with the body and some way to  pass on the charge to the blades.

Comment: @probably_someone - "I'm not sure why you think this idea is "questionable." Fan blades already become charged just through the triboelectric effect.." - Just my impression that it doesn't sound like a practical and efficient method of air filtration that is competitive with a standard furnace/AC system equipped with an electrostatic filter.

Comment: This really isn't a physics question, it's an engineering one.

Answer (score 1):

The device that allows you to make an electrical connection to a rotating object is called an **electrical slip ring**:
[image: slip ring]

However most slip rings are small diameter and you need quite a large diameter to avoid having to seriously restructure a ceiling fan.  So be prepared to make something yourself.
After you have a slip ring the next step would be to generate (large?) negative voltages. This can be accomplished with off the shelf components. The relevant keywords are **AC/DC converter** and **DC/DC step-up converter**. You may even be able to find a single component that does both the AC/DC conversion and the voltage step up. Connect the five fan blades to the negative terminal of your voltage converter and *ground the positive terminal*. Make sure to **include a fuse** of minimal current on the connection to the fan blades.